# Is the helping verb 'werden' mandatory in both passive clauses separated by an 'oder', or only at the very the end?

Tags: passive, ellipsis

I ran across the following sentence today:

> Anschließend können die Unterlagen per Post an XXX (Musterallee 1, 10101 Berlin) versendet oder persönlich im Büro während der Sprechzeiten eingereicht werden.

I would have intuitively added *werden* after *versendet*, even if it's mostly clear from the context and from its presence at the end of the second clause. As I'm not a native speaker I'd like to confirm my inkling and find out whether the original sentence is correct as-is (meaning it's OK to omit *werden* in the first instance), or if it's mandatory that *werden* appears at the end of both clauses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not mandatory and in fact, dropping all occurences of the same words at the same positions inside complicated lists is considered good style.

The tricky part is, there are are two alternatives which item has all the words listed and which has omissions.

> Er hat es kommen sehen können und (er hat (es (kommen (sehen)))) müssen.
>
> Sie wollte erst nichts (darüber erfahren), dann doch aber alles darüber erfahren.

The former sentence **must** have the omitted parts in the second item because the predicate of the first part would be misleading otherwise – *Er hat es können und (er hat es) kommen sehen müssen.* is a valid sentence with a different meaning.

In contrary, the latter sentence works either way and it's a matter of emphasis whether you omit the first or the second installment of *darüber erfahren*:

> Sie wollte erst nichts darüber erfahren, dann doch aber alles.

puts emphasis on *alles* instead of *erfahren* and sounds much snappier.

Comment: Interestingly, contrary to the original sentence,  verbs are stated explicitly in the first clause in your example, and omitted in the second.

Comment: Often both variants are possible. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The brackets around "sehen" are incorrect, I believe ("... und er hat es kommen müssen" does not work). Otherwise excellent example.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I think it's the opposite, the parts could be added from the inner bracket outwards: ... und sehen müssen, .. und kommen sehen müssen, ... und es kommen sehen müssen -- all seem correct. Not sure how to best depict that.

Comment: *... und ((((er) hat) es) ((kommen) sehen)) müssen.* Perhaps. Probably we need a regular expression with alternatives.